# Ordering fields by datetime from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, multiple-tables

I have two tables (`IncomingDocs`) and (`OutgoingDocs`) each have a field called `SubmitDate` (datatype `Datetime`) and `DepositNo` (datatype `Int`)
Each `DeposotNo` may have multiple `Submitdate` in a single table.

```
    For example;



_IncomingDocs table_

**DepositNo**  |  **SubmitDate**  

    1  |  10/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    1  |  12/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    2  |  10/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    3  |  10/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    3  |  13/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    4  |  20/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  

_OutgoingDocs table_

**DepositNo**  |  **SubmitDate**  

    1  |  11/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    2  |  15/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    3  |  12/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    3  |  14/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  
    4  |  19/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  

    SELECT DepositNo, SubmitDate  
    FROM IncomingDocs AS i, OutgoingDocs as o  
    WHERE DepositNo = 1  
    ORDER BY SubmitDate  

* The output of the query should be:

_Output table_

**DepositNo**  |  **SubmitDate**  
1  |  10/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  << From IncomingDocs table  
1  |  11/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  << From OutgoingDocs table  
1  |  12/3/2012 12:00:00 AM  << From IncomingDocs table
```

I want the output to be records of a specific DepositNo (specified in the WHERE clause) and ordered by the Submitdate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- you'll need 'UNION ALL' if you need to keep both rows from each table that
-- happen to be duplicate

```
SELECT DepositNo, SubmitDate  
FROM (  
     SELECT DepositNo, SubmitDate  
     FROM OutgoingDocs  
     WHERE DepositNo = 1 --Or a variable @MyDepositNo  
     UNION ALL --this will preserve duplicate rows if there are any between the two tables  
     SELECT DepositNo, SubmitDate  
     FROM IncomingDocs  
     WHERE DepositNo = 1 --as above  
) TT  
ORDER BY TT.SubmitDate
```

Comment: You don't need a subquery for this. Just remove the parentheses and the first `SELECT ... FROM`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if sql server supports union, but something like this

```
Select DepositNo, SubmitDate from IncomingDocs where DepositNo = X
UNION
Select DepositNo, SubmitDate from OutgoingDocs where DepositNo = X
ORDER BY SubmitDate
```

should probably work.

Comment: Thanks. It does work, but the UNION ALL works better in my case!